# Android Gauge Animation Help

Tags: android, performance, animation, gauge

I am new to android and i could really use some help here. I have two images both are PNG one represents a gauges and the second is the needle. I am trying to animate the needle according to speed (rpm), what i need help with is the animation portion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices.  You can use [Canvas 2D](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) and render it that way, or you can use the [Android Animation framework](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) with ImageViews.